# using a new Zalman PC case with an older OEM Lenovo MOBO M91P

Tags: motherboard, case, oem

Simple question what is the pin out for a old motherboard OEM Lenovo M91P. The front of the case requires on the usb and front case ports 9 pins when the mobo has 11 pins for usb and front case pins. I have read most of the threads for this type of situation and realize I may need to remove the pins from the connector and insert one at a time, but placing the pins in the wrong output will render the port on the mobo useless. please help if you need anymore information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

OEM parts are not intended for use with other generic parts, especially the motherboard in a new, non Lenovo case. The motherboard was designed to fit the Lenovo case and connectors.

You may try fitting the case's front panel connectors by following the pag. 77 of the [User's Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/0a23284.pdf).

**A satisfying result is not and cannot be guaranteed.**

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the 2 pins furthest from the key.  The remaining pins are the standard USB pinout.

Some people have reported that those 2 remaining pins need to be shorted to enable the port.  Ideally this should be done with a jumper.

[image]